# Elasticsearch TransportClient NetworkPlugin NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, client, transport

I am looking forward to integrate Elasticsearch in a Spring Boot Web Application. Here is my configuration that creates my Transport Client:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

private TransportClient client;

@Bean
public TransportClient client() throws UnknownHostException{

    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "5s")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
            .put("transport.tcp.compress", true)
            .put("cluster.name", "clusterName")
            .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", true)
            .build();

    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

    client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    return client;
}
```

When I start the Project I get following error and I don't know why:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.plugins.NetworkPlugin
```

Did I forgot to add a dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just stumbled over the same problem. Seems that the Elasticsearch docs aren't complete. In addition to the transport client dependency, you need to also add the elasticsearch dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You'll also need the log4j dependency, but that is clearly stated in the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_log4j_2_logger.html).

Comment: Hi I am getting   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultConnectionProfile java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultConnectionProfile
 at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.createBootstrap(Netty4Transport.java:207)    ...can u suggest something in this

Answer (score 2):

for me it looks like elastic search has a wrong dependency version in the pom

```
  <properties>
    <log4j.version>2.6.2</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>

    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>            
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId></exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>      
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

try to replace the version with 5.1.1 
well it looks like it also needs log4j ?!

best regards,
 noirabys

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21172) on Elasticsearch Github pages, SpringBoot starter manages some default dependencies, which defined the default version of ElasticSearch below 5.1.1, so that there is no such class.

You can explicitly define the property in your own pom to override its definition.

```
<properties>
    <elasticsearch.version>5.1.1</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
```

Hope it helps.