# Why I'm getting ClassNotFoundException while the package is listed as dependency in the pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've just asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105342/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-elasticsearch-plugins-networkplugin) since I was facing some ClassNotFoundException.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.plugins.NetworkPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

It's been pointed out to me that this exception means that the mentioned class is not found in the classpath at runtime. This is in the case that I have the container package in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So now my question is, how can a package be named as a dependency but some class in it be missing at runtime? And also, `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections` returns no conflict.

This is a Spring Boot project that I'm running using IntelliJ Idea in debug mode. I'm also using a dozen other packages in my code in the exact same way and they all work smoothly. But as soon as I add Elasticsearch, I face the mentioned exception.

Comment: Post all stack trace. Some one use magic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try deleting the downloaded dependency from your computer.

It is located at `~/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch` Assuming you keep maven dependencies in default location and running on a Mac OS X

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/*
```

Afterwards try re-downloading the dependency using

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try use one bellow version elasticsearch` of dependency. you can try one dependency from bellow dependencies :-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>5.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clean and build?, because sometimes when you add a dependency to your pom.xml you will see that the library is downloading but if you try to execute your project without build it you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the plugin part.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/plugins -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugins</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Maybe you also need the transport part:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See if this link helps: [Elasticsearch TransportClient NetworkPlugin NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062726/elasticsearch-transportclient-networkplugin-noclassdeffounderror)